# How to create a nested array in javascript

Tags: jquery

This is the HTML i got as a response

```
 <div id="ordersdiv">

   <div id="addtoordersdiv68">
      <div class="product-item">
        <ul>
         <form>
            <label  for="checkbox">Strawberry</label>
         </form>
          <ul>
      </div>
      <div class="Topping-details" id="68" style="display: block;"></div>
   </div>

   <div id="addtoordersdiv69">
      <div class="product-item">
         <ul>
         <form>
            <label  for="checkbox">Chocolate</label>
         </form>
          <ul>
      </div>
      <div class="Topping-details" id="69" style="display: block;">
         <section id="topping_tsection_69">
            <i id="topping-close"></i>
            <aside>
               <h6 class="tdHeading">Chocolate0</h6>
               <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
               <section class="secclass"><a class="tpActive">Honey Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
               <section class="secclass"><a class="tpActive">Caramel Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
               <section class="secclass"><a>Nutts and dry fruits10 gm</a></section>
            </aside>
            <aside>
               <h6 class="tdHeading">Chocolate1</h6>
               <section class="secclass"><a>Honey Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
               <section class="secclass"><a class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
               <section class="secclass"><a>Nutts and dry fruits10 gm</a></section>
            </aside>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

I need to parse  each div of class belonging to  **product-item** ,  capture the **label** text , then further  loop through div of class **Topping-details** div present with in that , and capture the **h6** and its corresponding **a** tags of class **tpActive** only , so that the output look this way (for the above data )

```
[
    {
        "name": "Chocolate",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Chocolate0",
                "value": [
                    "Honey Sauce  10 ML",
                    "Caramel Sauce  10 ML"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Chocolate1",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to achive the same using this way

```
var divdata = {
data: []
};


var    tvalue ;
var    tname ;
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.each($('#ordersdiv ul'), function(i, elem) {
            name = $(elem).find("label").text();
            if (name != 'undefined' && name!='') {
               tvalue = $(elem).find(".tpActive").text();
               tname = $(elem).find("h6").text();
                var toppings = [];
              var toppactive= [];
                toppactive.push(tvalue);
                 toppings.push( { "name": tname, "value": toppactive });
                divdata.data.push({
                    "name": name,
                     "toppings":toppings
                });
            }
        });
   console.log(JSON.stringify(divdata.data));
});
```

But i was getting output as

```
[{"name":"Strawberry","toppings":[{"name":"","value":[""]}]},{"name":"Chocolate","toppings":[{"name":"","value":[""]}]}]
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vv6GQ/2/

could anybody please help me hot to resolve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
var name;
var values = [];
var toppings = [];
var products = [];

//Iterating through the ul
$.each($('#ordersdiv ul'), function (i, elem) {
    name = $(elem).find("label").text();
    toppings = [];

    //In the assuption that child of chocolate contains chocolate* (like chocolate1, chocolate2, etc.)
    $('.Topping-details .tdHeading:contains("' + name + '")').each(function () {
        values = [];

        $(this).parent().find('.tpActive a').each(function () {
            //Creating values array
            values.push($(this).text());
        });

        //Creating topping array
        toppings.push({
            'name': $(this).text(), 
            'value': values
        });
    });
    //Creating product array 
    products.push({
        'name': $.trim($(this).text()), 
        'toppings': toppings
    });
});

console.log(products);
```

**Result**

```
[{
    "name": "Strawberry",
    "toppings": []
}, {
    "name": "Chocolate",
    "toppings": [{
        "name": "Chocolate0",
        "value": ["Honey Sauce  10 ML", "Caramel Sauce  10 ML"]
    }, {
        "name": "Chocolate1",
        "value": ["Honey with Carmel  10 ML"]
    }]
}]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RD3HZ/2/)